# PHP sends answer twice

Tags: php, html, onclick, xmlhttprequest, echo

I have some experience with Nodejs so I wanted to try some php too.
I want to make a GET request in a php file and get a response. While I get data, I receive them twice. I cheked the network tab on my browser and I see only one request. The html/javascript code works without a problem on nodejs, php persists on sending data twice. Why does this happen?

Html file:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello User!!</p>
    <button id="button">Get Request</button>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php?id=HI", true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 || this.status === 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);  
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send();
    };
</script>

</html>
```

test.php file:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    if($id == "HI"){
        echo ("Noice!");
    }else {
        echo ("I am sowwy :3");
    }
?>
```

*Disclaimer: "I understand this code does nothing important and always sends the same response. It is just an experiment to get myself familiar with php".*

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the responset twice but logging it twice.

onreadystatechange should be:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status === 200) console.log(this.responseText);  
  }
};
```